# What guarantees that the overloaded non-const method is invoked?

Tags: c++, recursion, signature

Given these 2 functions that modify and return a string:

```
// modify the original string, and for convenience return a reference to it
std::string &modify( std::string &str )
{
    // ...do something here to modify the string...
    return str;
}

// make a copy of the string before modifying it
std::string modify( const std::string &str )
{
    std::string s( str );
    return modify( s ); // could this not call the "const" version again?
}
```

This code works for me using GCC g++, but I don't understand why/how.  I'd be worried that 2nd function would call itself, leaving me with out-of-control recursion until the stack is exhausted.  Is this guaranteed to work?

Comment: This is tail recursion, most likely. I'm not sure the semantics of turning a const-ref call into a loop, so not posting an answer, but look up tail recursion and you'll find more info.

Comment: @peachykeen: No, it's not recursion at all.

Comment: Consider choosing a title that focuses the question better - e.g. "What guarantees that the overloaded non-const method is invoked?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two overloaded functions:

```
std::string &modify( std::string &str )
std::string modify( const std::string &str )
```

What you're passing is a non const-qualified `std::string`. Therefore, the function that takes the non const-qualified argument is a better fit. If that didn't exist, the compiler *could* convert the non const-qualified string to a const-qualified string to make the call, but for function overloading a call that requires no conversion is a better fit than a call that requires a conversion.

Answer (score 3):

```
return modify( s ); // could this not call the "const" version again?
```

No. It is **not** recursion. It would invoke the *other* overload whose parameter is `std::string &`.

It is because the type of the expression `s` is `std::string &` which matches with the parameter type of the other overloaded function.

In order to recurse, the argument at call-site needs to convert into `std::string const &`. But in your case, this conversion is **unnecessary** as there exists an overload  which doesn't require conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't recursion, it's overloading.  When you call the second function, the argument going into it is a constant string.  Inside that function, you call the other function which takes a non-const string.  What you're doing is stripping the const-ness of the string and a better way of doing that would be to use const_cast.

[I'll just link to this other stackoverflow thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853833/casting-non-const-to-const-in-c)

Comment: I don't want to remove constness. That would result in a seemingly const string getting modified!

Comment: What you can do is assign the non-const string by doing something like: std::string &str2 = const_cast<std::string &>(str).  str will remain constant but you'll be able to modify str2 all you want.