# Is there any way to cast const class* to non const class

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any way to cast const class* to non-const class*?

Background is that `QModelIndex->model()` returns const pointer to model. I need to access `model::setData`. But I can't.

Comment: It is possible (via `const_cast`) but also highly probable that you should not be doing it.

Comment: It returns that because you're not supposed to modify the object. (Read the documentation: "A const pointer to the model is returned because calls to non-const functions of the model might invalidate the model index and possibly crash your application.") This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I suspect that "`QModelIndex->model()` returns const pointer to model" should be "... returns pointer to const model". Be careful about what's `const`!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [casting non const to const in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853833/casting-non-const-to-const-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to cast const class* to non const class

Yes. That is what `const_cast` is for.

However, note that if you modify (non-mutable) state of a const object, then behaviour of the program is undefined. `const_cast` should not be used unless you can prove that the pointed object is non-const, or that the object won't be modified through the casted result.

Even when you can prove that you aren't modifying a const object, `const_cast` breaks encapsulation of the class, and may allow you to make changes that another part of the program is not expecting, which can potentially result in undefined or simply wrong behaviour. I would expect this to be true in case of calling `model::setData` on `QModelIndex->model()`.

`const_cast` is a code smell and is better to be avoided when it isn't needed. A reasonable use case for `const_cast` is to reuse implementation of a complex member function which for example has variants that return const or non-const reference to something based on the constness of `*this` but doesn't modify the object. Another use case is to call an ancient API that was written before const was introduced to the C language, and consequently uses pointers to non-const on functions that never modify the pointed objects.

Comment: Eg: writing an non-const function (mostly operator) by using const version with const_cast.

Comment: @LouisGo Good example. I added examples to the answer.